# Where to put a properties file in Struts 2?

Tags: properties, struts2, localization

I have a property file placed in the root of the web project in Java. I am using Struts 2.
My code is unable to read properties file. Where should I keep my properties file?

I have checked default path , it is where my Eclipse in installed. But I want that system should read file from project folder itself.

Answer (score 6):

Usually you should put the properties file to the `src` folder so your application is able to read the properties file when you do run your application the properties file is copied from the `src` folder to the `classes` folder. As far as you know the `classes` folder should be the project output folder, so it will be used as a `classpath` folder and application is able to load the properties file if it is on the `classpath`.

An example to get properties from the classpath:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();

try {
  //load properties from the class path
  prop.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myproperties.properties"));

  //get the property 
  System.out.println(prop.getProperty("mykey"));

} catch (IOException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
  throw ex;
}
```

However, you can load properties if you know the path to the file on the filesystem, in this case use

```
prop.load(new FileInputStream("/path/to/myproperties.properties"));
```

If you are talking about `struts.properties`

> The framework uses a number of properties that can be changed to fit
>   your needs. To change any of these properties, specify the property
>   key and value in an struts.properties file. The properties file can be
>   locate anywhere on the classpath, but it is typically found under
>   /WEB-INF/classes.

If you are looking for Message Resource properties it could be configured in the `struts.properties` or `struts.xml` the later is proffered.

```
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="path/to/resources/MessageResources"/>
```

the value is a filepath `src/path/to/resources/MessageResources.properties`

If you are looking for the proper way to configure your application consider the choice to use [EasyConf](http://easyconf.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thank you, now I don't have to hard code the absolute path of the property file every time. :)

Answer (score 5):

Property files will generally either go:

1. on the the classpath, e.g., for opening as a resource, or
2. at a location inaccessible to clients, e.g., under `/WEB-INF`

Which is more appropriate depends on your needs. Classpath-based files allow bundled default property files without configuration. For example, Log4J will look for `log4j.properties` at the root of the classpath as its default configuration file.

This can occasionally lead to issues, however, depending on class loading order: sometimes the system can pick up a "stray" config file. Configuring it yourself may still be preferable; I still tend towards the classpath, but config files are also commonly found in `WEB-INF`. Either method works, and both styles can be configured using JNDI, init params, environment variables, or system variables (e.g., `-D`).

Answer (score 4):

Keep your myPropertyFile.properties file in src folder (after build project you will find it in WEB-INF/classes) and access them using this code:

```
  Properties prop = new Properties();
  ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
  prop.load(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/myPropertyFile.properties"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you can save properties files in:
/src/com/cft/web/bundle/.
like,
/src/com/cft/web/bundle/LabelResources.properties
OR
/src/com/cft/web/bundle/Applicationresources.properties.

in fact its up to you to give whatever the path you like.

Just remember to add the correct complete path in web.xml/struts-config.xml

for ex=g.

1. in web.xml :

   ```html
           <description>Application Resources</description>
           <env-entry-name>ApplicationResources</env-entry-name>
           <env-entry-value>com.cft.web.bundle.ApplicationResources</env-entry-value>
           <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
   ```
2. In struts-config.xml

```html
<message-resources parameter="com.cft.web.bundle.LabelResources" key="yourPropertiesFileName"/>
```

Comment: Read careful the question, OP is using Struts2