# struts2 not load resource files

Tags: java, templates, struts2, resources

I have a problem with loading a resource file for a written action to struts 2.
Basically I put together action and resource files with the same name, but this does not load.

Below is the structure of the site:

> src/package/LoginAction.java
>
> src/package/LoginAction.properties

JSP

```
<s:form action="login.action" method="post" validate="true">
    <%-- <s:i18n name="LoginAction"> --%>
    <s:textfield name="username" key="label.username" size="20" />
    <s:password name="password" key="label.password" size="20" />
    <s:submit method="execute" key="label.login" align="center" />
    <%-- </s:i18n> --%>
</s:form>
```

The messages do not appear, either by using the tag `s:i18n` that without

Where am I doing wrong?

In the classpath I also have a `global.properties` mapped in `struts.xml` that is properly loaded.

Thanks to all

Comment: What messages do you want to appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`getText()`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionSupport.html#getText%28java.lang.String%29) method from ActionSupport:

```
<s:form action="login.action" method="post" validate="true">
    <s:textfield name="username" label="%{getText('label.username')}" size="20" />
    <s:password name="password"  label="%{getText('label.password')}" size="20" />
    <s:submit method="execute"   label="%{getText('label.login')}" align="center" />
</s:form>
```

Use `label` instead of `key`, [because `key` will set the `name` and `value` too](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/textfield.html):

> **key**: Set the key (name, value, label) for this particular component

Comment: `label="%{getText('label.username')}"`.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but nothing.
The problem is due to the displacement of properties file into the class file folder. 
If i try to put the files in the resource folder, tha application work correctly.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14585447/1654265 and ensure that your property file is being copied to class folder along with the .class file ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I solved it with the link.
Can I ask you something?
The resources that we talked about, are localized resources. From one page to the other, they lose localization.The global properties file recorded in struts.xml is not recovered as more tags who used it in the jsp do not display the requested property, present in the global.
This thing is driving me crazy.
you can record more files owned by the struts.xml? Since you can depend on this behavior?

Comment: You are welcome. Please remember to accept the answer if it helped, and if you have a different question, post it as a separate one to receive a better help. Regarding you last comment: non ho capito una mazza :D

Comment: :) Grazie, inglese da cani quasi quanto l'italiano :)