# Struts2: Best practice and best location for .properties files

Tags: properties, struts2

Based from the information I've read, in order for you to expose your properties to the .jsp, you will have to set the properties file at the same level as your action method. Currently, this is how my sample app directory looks like:

```
 app
 |
 | build 
 | src
   | some.package.login
     | Login.java
     | Login.properties
 | WebContent
   | META-INF
   | WEB-INF
   | login
     | login.jsp
```

As you can see, my `Login.properties` is in the same folder as my `Login.java`. This bothers me a lot seeing that once my application grows, there would be lots of property files that will be scattered around in various folders inside my `src` directory.

I was wondering if there is a way to consolidate all these property files into a single folder (probably `src/resources`) and tell Struts to look there for the property files just so that my property files aren't scattered around everywhere.

EDIT: I also wanted to know the best practices regarding property files. There are two kinds: the `local` and the `global`. I'm planning to place action-specific properties in local property files and I'm planning to put generic / static texts (to be rendered in the JSP) in the global property file. Is this a good practice?

Comment: May be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580274/where-to-put-a-properties-file-in-struts-2

Comment: The location in the source tree is irrelevant, only their position in the deployment. E.g., as govi says, use the Maven directory layout. Whether or not it makes sense to make your properties hyper-granular, that's something you'll need to decide for yourself. IMO it's more difficult to keep track of things that way; I prefer high-level property files that can be processed with standard properties tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to put properties files in separate folder.
Like this(Maven directory structure)

```
src/
   /main
      /java
           /com.dao
           /com.action
           /com.domain 
      /resources
           /displaytag.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have package.properties file in a folder that will aggregate all the properties (but only within the package of course)